# mercurial support in CruiseControl.NET - how to clean & update build folder?

Tags: mercurial, ccnet-config

I'm using the [Mercurial source control block](http://build.nauck-it.de/doc/CCNET/Mercurial%20Source%20Control%20Block.html) in CruiseControl.NET, and I have it set to `autoGetSource` but some of the files (such as version number, based on current time) change as part of the build. So for the next build, some of the files are changed so `autoGetSource` fails.

Is there a way I can tell CruiseControl.NET to do a `hg update -C` so changed files aren't a problem. Or is there a better way of cleaning out my build folder before starting a build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a hgrc file, either in the project, on the CC server, or in the CC user's profile directory, you could put:

```
[defaults]
update = -C
```

or perhaps better (since `[defaults]` is frowned on)

```
[hooks]
pre-update = hg revert --all --no-backup
```

Answer (score 6):

The CC.NET Mercurial source control block has the following setting:

> <revertModifications>true</revertModifications>

This will execute `hg revert --all --no-backup` before updating the source code for the build.

Also see `<purgeModifications />`

Ref.: [CruiseControl.NET server configuration documentation](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Mercurial_%28Hg%29)