# "Crosses Branches" error with Mercurial and CruiseControl.Net

Tags: mercurial, build, cruisecontrol.net

We are migrating to Mercurial, and of course, we need to update our CruiseControl.Net build process to use it instead of Visual SourceSafe.

We updated our CruiseControl config file with the following block:

```
<sourcecontrol type="hg" autoGetSource="true">
  <executable>C:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe</executable>
  <repo>https://bitbucket.org/GTSDevs/galaxy</repo>
  <workingDirectory>C:\Cruise Control\Releases\5.0.0\source</workingDirectory>
  <branch>master</branch>
  <multipleHeadsFail>false</multipleHeadsFail>
  <tagOnSuccess>true</tagOnSuccess>
  <timeout units="minutes">20</timeout>
</sourcecontrol>
```

This worked well until we pushed some code to our repository with a branch in it.  Now our build fails with the following error:

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: abort: crosses branches (merge branches or use --clean to discard changes)
. Process command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe update -r master --noninteractive
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Mercurial.Mercurial.GetSource(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Build(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

All the information I can find on the error appears to pertain to doing an `update`.

Can anyone help out with getting past this?

Is there something more we should be doing in our ccnet.config file to support Mercurial?

Comment: Is it a named branch you added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- the best way would be to add a new parameter to the Mercurial source control block in order to add the `--clean` command line parameter
- [mercurial support in CruiseControl.NET - how to clean & update build folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449646/)